# $\sigma$-algebra generated by function

Tags: measure-theory

I have no idea how to calculate $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y=\sin(\pi x)$. I'm looking for hints and suggestions to calculating the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Do you mean $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, and metric space: $([0,1] , \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]} , \mathcal{L})$

Answer (score 0):

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra s.t. $Y$ is measurable w.r.t to that algebra.

So the $\sigma$-algebra need to contain all pre-images w.r.t to $Y$ of borel sets.

Instead of checking all borel sets it's sufficient to check intervals of the form $(-\infty,c]$.

So you have to figure out how the sets $Y^{-1}\left((-\infty,c]\right)$, shortly written as $\{Y \le c\}$, look like.

Maybe start with $c = -1, c = 0, c=1, c = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and try to generalize it for an arbitrary x.